# Como faco para retornar um item existente em minha enumerable através do Contains?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

Tenho uma enumerable, e pretendo consultar através de um código por parâmetro. se a enumerable "Contains" Código, então ela me retornara todos os itens que estiverem com esse Código.

Veja estava tentando fazer assim:

```
public IEnumerable<Relacao> Listar(int Codigo)
{
    return this.Context.Relacoes.Contains(codigo);
}
```

Answer (score 5):

O método `Contains` geralmente retorna um valor booleano (verdadeiro ou falso) e não uma enumeração.

Você pode usar `Where` para criar um filtro sobre as `Relacoes`, e então usar uma condição para este filtro, de forma que somente os elementos que batem com a condição sejam retornados:

```
public IEnumerable<Relacao> Listar(int Codigo)
{
    // assumindo que uma "relação" possua a propriedade `Codigo`
    return this.Context.Relacoes
               .Where(rel => rel.Codigo == Codigo)
               .ToList();
}
```

O `ToList` no final serve para obter os dados do banco de dados no momento em que é chamada. Se não fizer isso, os dados só serão obtidos no futuro quando a enumeração resultante for utilizada. Sem o `ToList` teriamos um tipo de avaliação preguiçosa.

Se o seu objetivo é ter uma avaliação preguiçosa, então deve remover a chamada do `ToList`, mas neste caso, recomendo que troque o tipo de retorno também para [`IQueryable<Relacao>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.linq.iqueryable%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

```
public IQueryable<Relacao> Listar(int Codigo)
{
    // assumindo que uma "relação" possua a propriedade `Codigo`
    return this.Context.Relacoes
               .Where(rel => rel.Codigo == Codigo);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

olha, você pode fazer o seguinte:

```
public IEnumerable<Relacao> Listar(int codigo)
{
    return this.Context.Relacoes.Where(relacao => relacao.Codigo == codigo);
}
```

Caso `Codigo` seja a PK de `Relacao` e você queira retornar apenas uma `Relacao`, faça o seguinte:

```
public Relacao Consultar(int codigo)
{
    return this.Context.Relacoes.Find(codigo);
}
```